# After how many rows should one leave the current job/position?

Tags: work-environment, conflict

In the last one and a half year, I had two rows with my boss. Both times I was thinkinq to quit but somehow I remained in my position. Just for an explanation, by rows I mean exchanging several emails with strong comments on productivity and un-kept promises. In the second time, my boss reported me to the director, that he is not satissfied with me, but she somehow sided with my case. Now our relationship is OK, I think, but I fear that next time I will have to/should quit?

Is there any unwritten rule when should one leave the job if there are some misunderstanding with the boss?

Comment: Are the issues *resolved* (or would this just keep happening or getting worse)? As in: are they now happy with your productivity and do they feel you're keeping your promises? Have they explicitly told you this? Have you asked? Do you consider the words and actions of your boss to be *reasonable*? The answers to those questions should hint at whether your job is at risk (and whether you should be looking for another one). Although none of this would matter if you are unhappy with your job, in which case you should be looking for another one either way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there any unwritten rule when should one leave the job if there are some misunderstanding with the boss?

General rule of thumb when you're unhappy is to get another job before you quit. Don't base it on personal issues without that, unemployment isn't fun.

Answer (score 5):

You never *have to quit*. It is in most cases better for you if you are pushed instead of jumping yourself. And when you think your job is at risk, or when you think you want to leave, you first look for a new job. And when you found one, and a legally binding contract is signed, that's when you give notice.

One thing you didn't say who was making comments on productivity and unkept promises, and if that person was right or wrong. But then, your boss is not the boss of the company. He is just one level above you, your manager or supervisor, so with very little power, and the director above him has sided with you at least once, so you are not in a bad position.

If there is another "misunderstanding", that is if your manager attacks you once more, then you think about whether his accusations are true or not. If he is right, fair enough. If he is wrong, think about how much it affects you. Some people in your position wouldn't care because they know they are right, some would break out in tears, most are somewhere in between. If it affects you negatively, you talk to HR / the director and / or start looking for a new job.

Comment: _"It is in most cases better for you if you are pushed instead of jumping yourself."_ - Could you please clarify on why it is better being pushed than jump - is it more beneficial in terms compensation? I try to understand but can't get the reasoning..

Answer (score 1):

Conflict is a part of daily life, especially in the workplace. You are never going to work anywhere for a reasonable amount of time where you will have no conflict. Handling it properly is a requirement of success. When handled properly, its a good thing. A catalyst for growth. It just depends on how you handle it. If you're civil, and your responses are measured, you should have nothing to worry about. But this depends entirely on the maturity and professionalism of your boss. Did he get heated, insulting, or aggressive in any way? Or was it a civil back-and-forth? No answer to this question can truly be complete because it all comes down to the kind of professional your boss is and your own professionalism. If you handled it poorly, or you cant deal with the fallout of such conflict then changing jobs isn't going to fix anything.